# Drawing a graph with some properties displayed with Boost Graph Library

Tags: boost-graph

everyone. I have been using Boost Graph Library but it's quite difficult to me. Recently, I have tried to draw the following graph (I used .dot file to display coz I don;t have enough reputation to attach a picture, sorry for any inconvenience caused)

```
enter code here
graph{
    0[label = "Prof Nachiket", color = blue];
    1[label = "Nick", color = red];
    2[label = "Lam", color = green];
    0 -- 1[label = "Supervisor"];
    0 -- 1[label = "Supervisor"];
    1 -- 2[label = "Co-worker" ];

}
```

And then turn it into a picture with Graphviz. However, I got no idea how to add information such as label, color into edges of graph. In other words, I have a little or no idea how to draw above graph by using Boost Graph Library. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot

Best Regards

Nick Ng

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a boost graph in graphviz with one of the properties displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181183/how-to-print-a-boost-graph-in-graphviz-with-one-of-the-properties-displayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***NEW ANSWER***

Its a dube, see

- [How to print a boost graph in graphviz with one of the properties displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181183/how-to-print-a-boost-graph-in-graphviz-with-one-of-the-properties-displayed)
- [boost graph library - minimal example of vertex colors and graphviz output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772589/boost-graph-library-minimal-example-of-vertex-colors-and-graphviz-output)
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html
- [How to print a graph in graphviz with multiple properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369115/how-to-print-a-graph-in-graphviz-with-multiple-properties-displayed)
- [drawing custom BGL graph with graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398865/drawing-custom-bgl-graph-with-graphviz)
- [C++ Boost Graph Library: outputting custom vertex properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235927/c-boost-graph-library-outputting-custom-vertex-properties)

***OLD ANSWER:***

There are many resources online which specifies how to draw advanced graphs using Graphviz. Here are some which I have found useful in the past:

- www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf‎
- www.graphviz.org/content/attrs
- www.graphviz.org/content/output-formats
- www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html
- http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/

The last link is an online render, very useful if you dont have graphviz on your machine.
For your specific question here's a simple example using colored edges and labels:

**Dot:**

```
graph{
    0 [label = "Prof Nachiket", color=blue shape=ellipse ];
    1 [label = "Nick", color = red shape=Mdiamond];
    2 [label = "Lam", color = green shape=diamond];
    0 -- 1[label = "Supervisor" color=pink];
    1 -- 2[label = "Co-worker" color=red penwidth=2];
}
```

**Img:**

[image: Image generated from above dot code]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But seems you have misunderstood my query. First I need to build up everything about my graph by using Boost Graph Library, then it's going to be turned into my above attached code

Comment: I see, sorry for that! I'll post a new answer shortly.

Comment: Your question has been asked many times before. I have linked to related/similar question and based on that info you should be able to solve your issue.